# Binary Search not doing running properly

Tags: python

## The code just returns the number I input. Not the string for found, not sure why? I've tried everything and its not working :(

```
 array = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 
23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 
    47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

targetValue = int(input())


def binarySearch(array, targetValue):
    min = 0
    max = len(array) - 1
    found = 'Number is not in array'
    
    while (min <= max):

        middle = (min + max)/2

        if array[middle] == targetValue:
            found = 'We found the number in the array!'
    
        else:
            if targetValue < array[middle]:
                max = middle - 1
            else: 
                min = middle + 1
    return found 


index = binarySearch(array, targetValue)
print (index)
```

Comment: Because you don't return `found`

Comment: You never change `targetValue` inside the function, and simply `return` it at the end, so you'll always get that same value out. PS you also need to use the `int` function to convert the result of `input` (which is a string) to a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the return statement into the if statement:

```
array = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 
23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 
    47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

targetValue = int(input())


def binarySearch(array, targetValue):
    min = 0
    max = len(array) - 1
    found = 'Number is not in array'

    while (min <= max):

        middle = (min + max)//2

        if array[middle] == targetValue: # If condition is met
            found = 'We found the number in the array!' 
            return found  # Jump out of the function

        else:
            if targetValue < array[middle]:
                max = middle - 1
            else: 
                min = middle + 1



index = binarySearch(array, targetValue)
print (index)
```

Comment: I've changed the line of code to say return found. I also added "int" to targetValue = input(), so it now reads int targetValue = input() but VS code says its wrong?

Comment: it says int targetValue = input() is invalid syntax? Whats the proper way to convert input from user from a string to integer?

Comment: `targetValue = int(input()) `

Comment: That seems to work! The code for some reason still doesn't return anything. Terminal asks me for input, I put in 67 or some number and the code keeps running, doesn't crash or anything. I never get back found.

Comment: Try adding `print(max,min)` right above `return targetValue`.

Comment: it doesn't print

Comment: I see the problem. You have an extra indent for the `return`.

Comment: and you forgot to change the value of `middle` for each iteration.

Comment: I've updated the code of what I have, when I indent 'return found' terminal returns " Number is not in array" even when it is in the array. If left where it currently is, terminal doesn't return anything. I've also moved middle inside the while loop so it gets updated.